# How to git push subtree from a local branch to heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, version-control

I have a rails app that is not at the root of my git repository. 
/repositoryroot/myapp

When I normally push the app to heroku, I use `git subtree -P myapp/ push heroku master`.

Now I've added a staging app on heroku and I have some changes under a local branch that I want to push to the staging app.

The heroku docs say I can push a local branch to heroku master with `git push staging localbranch:master`

But when I try to combine the two and do `git subtree -P myapp/ push staging localbranch:master` I get an error from git.

```
error: src refspec d24e1<some more hex gibberish>202a54e:refs/heads/localbranch does not match any.

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mystagingapp.git'
```

How do I push the subfolder that is the root of my app /repositoryroot/myapp from my local branch to heroku staging?
Do I need a special refspec? Or is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to answer my own question.

`git push staging \`git subtree split -P myapp/ localbranch\`:refs/heads/master`

Comment: since your question is solved by your self, you can put your method as a answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question.

```
git push staging `git subtree split -P myapp/ localbranch\`:refs/heads/master
```